# <div class in textbox why?

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList(DropDownListSelectCategory.SelectedItem.Value);

  SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems();

   foreach (SPListItem news in items)
   {                        
      TextBoxContents.Text = news["Contents"].ToString();
   }
```

I Have written following code i get this in my textbox

`<div class="ExternalClass59460DDBFF63443BA0E2D2715A82F7DD">TTTTEEEEXXXT</div>`

Answer (score 3):

is the textbox a rich text field instead of a standard textbox?

if it is you need to change itemstyle.xsl and add the following:

```
<div class="description">
     <xsl:value-of select="@Body" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
</div>
```

That should solve your styling issue, what you see is ment to be hidden :)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopmentlegacy/thread/9649edea-fb87-456b-a43d-40e730a698f8/

or through code use regex

```
Regex.Replace(currentItem["Your Field Name"].ToString(), "<.*?>", string.Empty);
```

http://www.go4sharepoint.com/Forum/externalclass-enhanced-rich-text-fields-7091.aspx

and

http://www.sp-blogs.com/blogs/adnan/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=15

hope it helps :)